# NodeJS CPanel DNS_PROBE_POSSIBLE

Tags: javascript, node.js, cpanel

Hi i just got a web hosting and a domain. I installed a nodejs application on cpanel but it returns me DNS_PROBE what should i do?

indexjs

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    var message = 'It works!\n',
        version = 'NodeJS ' + process.versions.node + '\n',
        response = [message, version].join('\n');
    res.end(response);
});
server.listen();
```

I tried re-installing but it didn't work